# How can I check if a key exists in my db using Firebase REST API?

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the Firebase REST API. I would like to check to see if a key exists in my database before writing to it. If it does not exist, I want to create it and write a set of default data to that key. If it does exist, I want to update the data at that key.

Right now I am attempting this by sending a GET request for that key, as in this example:

```
curl 'https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/rest/saving-data/fireblog/posts.json?print=pretty'
```

and checking the response data. However, while the response data is empty if the key does not exist, it also appears to be empty if there was any other type of error retrieving the data.

Is there another way to check if a key exists using the REST API, like a URI parameter I can use? If not, is there a way to tell if the response data is empty because the key does not exist, or because there was an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The REST API will return a `200` status code and a body of `null` when the location is empty. Other errors will return a `4xx` or `5xx` status code.

```
curl -I https://example.firebaseio.com/does/not/exist.json

HTTP1/1 200 OK
...
```

Comment: I thought that this was working for me, but I have found that occasionally that the REST API returns a status code of 200 with a null response body, even when the user does exist. I can't figure out why this is happening - it only happens on occasion. Any other suggestions I might use in conjunction with the status code to ensure that the query is correctly reporting the user doesn't exist?

Comment: @Sarah did you find a solution to your issue or are you still experiencing problems?